# How to make sure NSUrlSession does not fetch cached pages?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I'm using `NSUrlSession` to download the contents of an HTML page (so I can parse it, against my will). My problem is that iOS seems to be caching the page with my app, so that even if I update this page on the server, my app keeps seeing the old version (this persists until I delete and reinstall the app).

How can I get NSUrlSession to always download a fresh copy?

**Edit**: not that complicated, just had to change this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
```

to this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData 
    timeoutInterval:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your `NSURLSessionConfiguration`'s `requestCachePolicy` to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

Comment: I went with the sledgehammer: `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData`